# Parse JSON error returned from Cloud Endpoints (google app engine)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

In my Endpoints API method I have a line of code that will throw an error if an email address is already taken by a user:

`throw new BadRequestException("The Email address is already taken.");`

In my Android Client I am trying to parse this error in order to display it to the user:

```
  try {
            myApi.registerUser(registrationInput).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String jsonError = e.getMessage();
            try {
                JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(jsonError);
                // myError should be "The Email address is already taken."
                String myError = jsonRootObject.optString("message").toString();

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace(); 
            }
}
```

However I get an error in Android Studio:

> org.json.JSONException: Value 400 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be
>   converted to JSONObject

the value of the jsonError string is this:

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "The Email address is already taken.",
      "reason": "badRequest"
    }
  ],
  "message": "The Email address is already taken."
}
```

As you can see I am trying to get the `message` of the error.

I think the problem is that the returned error starts with `400 Bad Request` and not an open bracket.

**Question: Is there a correct way to parse the Cloud Endpoints error to get the code and the message so I can display it to my user?**

I saw some Java code [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/errors) in the docs that looked like this:

```
try {
  commitResponse = datastore.commit(commitRequest);
} catch (DatastoreException e) {
  int code = e.getCode();
  String method = e.getMethodName();
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(e.getMessage()));
  JSONObject error = json.getJSONObject("error")
      .getJSONArray("errors")
      .getJSONObject(0);
  String reason = error.getString("reason");
  String message = error.getString("message");
  // ... process error ...
}
```

But I do not think this is for Android. I think it is non-android Java code? At any rate, I couldn't get the imports right to even make it work but maybe it provides a clue.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You could make your own parser for the json error string. Remove the first line and your good to go.

Comment: @Dexter Yeah that is what my next step was going to be but I wanted to ask on SO first because it seems so stupid to have to do that... =(

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions thrown by Endpoints contain the HTTP Response received as their message. Therefore, the response received is essentially a standard [HTTP Response Resource](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-6) as defined by [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945) where the first line is the `Status-Line` of the response and the remainder is the optional `message-body`.

Though slightly cumbersome for quickly accessing the JSON message body, this seems like a relatively simple way of granting the developer access to the complete HTTP response, should that be required.

As suggested previously by @Dexter, removing the first line from the result of `getMessage()` should be sufficient for returning strictly the JSON message body. If you later encounter additional headers causing problems with this parsing solution, you could search for the end of the HTTP headers instead and parse from there until the end of the `String` for the JSON message body.